# Converting Java to C# - Create image & get graphics

Tags: java, c#

Hi I'm trying to convert some code from java to c#.

```
picture = createImage(x1, y1); 
        g1 = picture.getGraphics();
```

It's only simple but I can't find anywhere how I'd write this in c#. If anyone can give a quick idea on how i'd do it thatd be great!
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soemthing like this:

```
Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
```

You can also go through MSDN: [How to: Create Graphics Objects for Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054(v=vs.110).aspx)